# RMarkdown: Header Summary/Overview in RStudio?

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio

I have a long RMarkdown file that is organized with Headings. Scrolling through to find a Heading of interest has become time consuming.

Is there a way to display a summary/overview of all Headings in RStudio?  Ideally one that is interactive so that I can click a Heading and automatically navigate to that location in the RMarkdown file?  For instance in the following example, imagine each heading has a single code chunk under it, and Heading 2.1.2 is on line 2400.  How can I easily navigate to this Heading 2.1.2 without scrolling through the RMarkdown file to find it manually?

In reality I have many more Headings.  I've been hiding code chunks by clicking the arrow next to the Heading, but I'm hoping there is a better way to navigate through.

Thank you!

```
# Heading 1

## Heading 1.1

### Heading 1.1.1

### Heading 1.1.2

### Heading 1.1.3


# Heading 2

## Heading 2.1

### Heading 2.1.1

### Heading 2.1.2

### Heading 2.1.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Rmarkdown file opened with Rstudio, you can click on the "outline" button to enable a table of content next to your Rmd file, where you can navigate to different sections of your Rmd conveniently by clicking onto your desired header.

[image: outline_button]

Under the Rmarkdown section in the global option, you can choose whether to display section header only or to also include code chunks in the table of content.

[image: global_option]

Comment: Thank you!  I don't know why I never noticed that Outline button before.